# Spring @RequestMapping on controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC 3.1.3.

I'd like to do the same as the example shown in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping). `@RequestMapping` on the controller and a 'root' method.

But Spring does not handle correctly.

Here's my code :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String list() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

When I try `http://localhost/test-project/test` I get a 404 Not Found but it's working when I use `http://localhost/test-project/test/`.

Does anyone know how I can fix this ?

Thanks,

Smoky

**EDIT:**

Here's the log :

```
16:13:36,085 | DEBUG | RequestMappingHandlerMapping:209 | Looking up handler method for path /test
16:13:36,087 | DEBUG | RequestMappingHandlerMapping:219 | Did not find handler method for [/test]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the method requestMapping tag on the method to...

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"", "/", "/list"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Edit addition from comment :

Have you tried setting the controller to `@RequestMapping("/test*")`

Comment: Already tried. Sorry I didn't specify. I added the log in the question.

Comment: Have you tried setting the controller to `@RequestMapping("/test*")`

Comment: That was nice suggestion but it's not working either :(.

Comment: I extracted the code I posted of my project to put it in a simple test project and it's working. I don't understand -_-

Comment: Check the logs when the applications (startup/deploying) , spring scans the annotations and maps the bean to the url . usualy it prints all possible mapping based on url. that might give clue

Comment: Thanks but that's what I do. I set the log level to DEBUG and look for the issue. Curiously, I did not find the `/test` but `/test/` was mapped. The code worked alone so I looked in the config (especially spring security) but didn't find anything. I rewrote the code, cleaned the project and *WTF* it is working...

Comment: The clean probably got rid of some old binaries.  It might've been publishing old code.

Comment: Yes :/. 45min of life time lost :p. Thanks anyway for your help !

Comment: Don't think of it as _time lost_, you have learnt something! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use wildcard in your Controller level `@RequestMapping`:

```
@RequestMapping("/test*")
```